# Output after building chromium source code on ubuntu linux

Tags: build, ubuntu-10.04, chromium

I followed [these steps](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions) to build chromium source code on linux. 
**I build only chrome.** Finally i have finished it successfully.

For output i opened **out/Debug** directory, i found some files but, i don't know which file is executable or anything extra i have to do to create executable. I didn't get any information from above link also after building source code.

Please help me regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever compiled code before? Do you know how to identify an executable file?

Comment: I found many files as type executable in their properties. I need the correct chrome executable file generated after building chromium source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Run the shell script file **chrome-wrapper** in out/Debug directory, it launches Chrome Browser automatically.

Answer (score 0):

After building chrome (via `make chrome`, or the like), you'll have an executable binary at `out/Debug/chrome`. Other packages (notably the unittests) generate similar binaries: `out/Debug/unit_tests` or `out/Debug/browser_tests` for example.